# HTML / adnantopal slimmenu for mobile devices

Tags: javascript, php, html, menu

For the users of this slimmenu, you know that on the top left corner of the mobile menu
there is the word "MENU" (like shown on the image).

[image: menu image]

I would like to know where in the php or js files I should change this so that the word "MENU"
can be changed by another word or maybe even a logo (so a png image).

I know it isn't in the html files so please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is not really awnserable without any code and without knowing under which conditions you want the word to change.

Comment: You are right but I was targeting people who had already worked with this slimmenu. Since my question is a simple one , just want to know where I can change the word MENU to something else in the code.